# Hadoop M/R jobs chaining does not work with no exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to chain two sequential M/R jobs in hadoop with the following code. Basically, right after the first job completes, I make another job that uses the first job's output as input. But the code does not produce the output for the second job, and it didn't throw any exception. Can you guys help me spot where might be wrong? I appreciate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
            .getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("Usage: jobStats <in> <out> <job>");
        System.exit(2);
    }


    conf.set("job", otherArgs[2]);
    Job job = new Job(conf, "job count");
    job.setJarByClass(jobStats.class);
    job.setMapperClass(jobMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(jobReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(jobReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);        
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);           
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

    boolean completionStatus1 = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (completionStatus1 == true)
    {
        Job job2 = new Job(conf, "job year ranking");
        job2.setJarByClass(jobStats.class);
        job2.setPartitionerClass(ChainedPartitioner.class);
        job2.setGroupingComparatorClass(CompKeyGroupingComparator.class);
        job2.setSortComparatorClass(CompKeyComparator.class);

        job2.setMapperClass(ChainedMapper.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(ChainedReducer.class);
        job2.setPartitionerClass(ChainedPartitioner.class);
        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(CompositeKey.class);
        job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        Path outPath = new Path(otherArgs[1] + "part-r-00000"); // this is the hard-coded output of first job
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if (fs.exists(outPath))
        {
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, outPath);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path("/user/tony/output/today"));

            boolean completionStatus2 = job2.waitForCompletion(true);
            if (completionStatus2 == true)
            {
                fs.delete(outPath, true);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else System.exit(1);
        }
        else System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the exit code from the program?

Comment: if the job completes successfully, it returns 0, otherwise 1

Comment: You need to make sure your final reducer is actually getting something to write

Answer (score 0):

The ChainedMapper and ChainedReducer classes are used to string together multiple mappers in a single Map Reduce job.  Something like M1-M2-M3-R-M4-M5.

In your case you want to run two complete map reduce jobs in a row. Just specify a real map for the second job.

Comment: My understanding is that ChainedMapper/Reducer does not work for me, because I have two reducers that need to be chained, and ChainedMapper/Reducer classes allow only one reducer, right?

Comment: that is right.  you should run two jobs in a row, like you're doing.  But the mapper you have provided to the second job in OP is a chainedmapper with 0 component mappers in it.

Comment: My second mapper is just named ChainedMapper.java, oh this might be a conflict with the systems ChainedMapper, right?